# Why parallel_accumulate is slower?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I tried to test the difference between parallel accumulation and serial accumulation with below program on my 8 kernel computer with gcc/ubuntu. It appears that the serial version is always faster no matter I turn the optimization compiler option on or off.

```
class ParalellAccumulator
{
public:
template<typename Iterator, typename T>
struct accumulate_block
{
    void operator()(Iterator first, Iterator last, T& result)
    {
        result = std::accumulate(first, last, result);
    }
};

template<typename Iterator, typename T>
static T parallel_accumulate(Iterator first, Iterator last, T init)
{
    unsigned long const length = std::distance(first, last);
    if (!length)
        return init;

    unsigned long const min_per_thread = 25;
    unsigned long const max_threads = (length + min_per_thread - 1)
            / min_per_thread;

    unsigned long const hardware_threads =
            std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

    unsigned long const num_threads = std::min(
            hardware_threads != 0 ? hardware_threads : 2, max_threads);

    unsigned long const block_size = length / num_threads;

    std::vector<T> results(num_threads);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_threads - 1);

    Iterator block_start = first;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < (num_threads - 1); ++i)
    {
        Iterator block_end = block_start;
        std::advance(block_end, block_size);
        threads[i] = std::thread(accumulate_block<Iterator, T>(),
                block_start, block_end, std::ref(results[i]));
        block_start = block_end;
    }
    accumulate_block<Iterator, T>()(block_start, last,
            results[num_threads - 1]);

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),
            std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    return std::accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), init);

}

static void test()
{
    std::vector<double> rawData(100000000);
    std::cout << "Accumulating " << rawData.size() << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rawData.size(); i++)
    {
        rawData[i] = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        //std::cout << rawData[i] << std::endl;
    }

    clock_t start = clock();
    double result = 0.0;
    result = std::accumulate(begin(rawData), end(rawData), result);
    long diff = clock() - start;
    std::cout << "Serial result: " << result << " in "
            << (double) diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << std::endl;

    start = clock();
    result = 0.0;
    result = parallel_accumulate(begin(rawData), end(rawData), result);
    diff = clock() - start;
    std::cout << "Parallel result: " << result << " in "
            << (double) diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << std::endl;

}
};
```

With optimization option on, the result is:

```
Accumulating 100000000
Serial result: 5.00011e+07 in 0.09 seconds
Parallel result: 5.00011e+07 in 0.25 seconds
```

With optimization option off, the result is:

```
Accumulating 100000000
Serial result: 5.00011e+07 in 0.85 seconds
Parallel result: 5.00011e+07 in 1.51 seconds
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Summing an array or vector of numbers is memory bandwidth limited, as the cpu can add much quicker than it can read memory. Having multiple threads results in more cache conflicts.

Comment: maybe time spend to create threads matters? Measure it separately and print.

Comment: Not much work being done there and `clock()` is hardly an optimal timer. But still for me using `std::chrono` the parallel version takes 5ms vs. 8ms for the sequential one. For a ten times larger array the timing is 38 vs. 82ms.